# Find the latest time in a series

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query that I am trying to use to find the first and the last reading of a patient:

```
REC.inpatient_data_id
        ,Rec.PAT_ID
        ,IP_FLT_DATA. Template_ID
        , IP_FLT_DATA.Template_Name
        , IP_FLT_DATA.Display_Name
        ,IP_FLO_GP_DATA.FLO_MEAS_NAME
        ,IP_FLO_GP_DATA.DISP_NAME
        ,MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID
        ,MEAS.MEAS_VALUE
        ,MEAS.RECORDED_TIME
        ,MEAS.line
        ,Min(Recorded_Time) Over(Partition By Rec.Pat_ID Order By Meas.Recorded_TIME) First_Time
        ,Max(Recorded_TIME) Over(Partition By Rec.Pat_ID Order By Meas.Recorded_TIME) Final_Time
FROM HCCLSC. IP_FLWSHT_REC REC
  LEFT OUTER JOIN HCCLSC.IP_FLWSHT_MEAS MEAS ON REC.FSD_ID=MEAS.FSD_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN HCCLSC.IP_FLO_GP_DATA ON IP_FLO_GP_DATA.FLO_MEAS_ID = MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN HCCLSC.IP_FLT_DATA  ON IP_FLT_DATA.TEMPLATE_ID = MEAS.FLT_ID 
WHERE   --IP_FLO_GP_DATA.DISP_NAME like '%disorganized%'
  REC.inpatient_data_id=212126860810
  and 
  MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID in (12436741, 12436742, 12436743, 12436744, 12436745, 12436746)
```

The Min(Recorded_Time) gives me the correct answer for all rows.
However the Max(Recorded_Time) just spits out the Recorded_Time back to me, Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in this case.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Order By Meas.Recorded_TIME`. It narrows your window by silently applying `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

```
 Min(Recorded_Time) Over(Partition By Rec.Pat_ID) First_Time
,Max(Recorded_TIME) Over(Partition By Rec.Pat_ID) Final_Time
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.  I wasn't aware it would add that issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to find, when you don't know about it. It's syntactic sugar for getting running totals more readable (`SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY something)`).